# Updating SQL row by a click of HTML button and php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a simple comment system with rate for each comment.

(Did you like this comment?) question with two buttons "**Yes**" and "**No**".

I am trying to find a simple way that on clicking the button it updates in the database the number of votes if said yes or no.

I looked in several places over the internet but there was nothing so specific except that I know it is not a big problem and can be done easily.

what is the column type supposed to be and how to write the query on the html button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you create two tables:

**`Comments`:**

- `CommentId`,
- `CommentText`,
- ... other columns

**`Votes`:**

- `VoteId`,
- `CommentId` (on which comment this vote),
- `UserId` (how rated the comment),
- `Liked` (a flag 0 (no) or 1(yest)).

When clicking the HTML button, insert a new row in the votes table.

Then to get a number of votes, you can join the two tables and count the number from the second table with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  c.CommentId,
  COUNT(COALESCE(v.VoteId, 0)) AS TotalVotes
FROM Comments AS c
LEFT JOIN votes AS v ON c.commentId = v.CommentId
GROUP BY c.CommentId;
```

You can also query for the likes = 0 or likes = 1 individually if you want, this just an example.

Comment: Thank you my friend this is helpful and that was exactly what I needed, long live Rab3a w rabena ma3akom fi masr, wa7ashetni :D

Answer (score 3):

You're asking different questions with some underlining implications here. I'll try to help you figure it out.

First, the database.

There are several things to consider here :

- Do you have users ? If you do, you will have to create a voting table linking your users with their votes, as suggested in a previous answer. You do not want to use COUNT to know how many votes there are though. This is time consuming on a big database. Just create a counter field in your comments table and increment/decrement it so you don't have to count every time.
- If you don't have users and anyone can vote on the site, you may want to consider using a cookie or some kind of temporary identifier (like their IP address, even though it isn't reliable at all) to prevent bots from spamming the votes. It is, in itself, quite a complex problem and I would advise you to limit the votes to registered users.
- The "vote" field in itself will be a TINYINT, as suggested.

Now the query in itself.

Once again, several possibilities depending of your knowledge.

- The easiest way is to create a form, send the results to the same page and have php check is post data is set when loading the page. If so, send a query with the post data. There are lots of tutorials explaining how to do that properly (with data sanitation and such).
- However, the aforementionned solution will reload the whole page. This is messy and not really useful. To creater a smoother user experience, you should do this in AJAX. If you're new to it but want to try it out, you should check out [jquery](http://jquery.com/), which is a good javascript library.

Comment: Wow this is quite interesting, you got me thinking twice, I have not used AJAX before, I will check this and contact you back if I found any problems. Thank you my friend =)

Answer (score 0):

The data type can be anything you like. CHAR, VARCHAR, TINYINT, or BOOL are all popuar choices. Personally, I'd go with TINYINT.

As you say, this is a simple task. I'm sure that there is discussion out there on assigning actions to buttons.